# QUiLoader doesn't see signals defined in a custom plugin on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5, qt-designer

I'm using QUiLoader to create widgets from ui files at runtime.

I want to access widgets from a designer plugin I have.

Everything works fine but on Mac for some reason Qt fails to connect signals when doing so.

```
QObject::connect: signal not found
```

The widgets are loaded correctly, just the signals don't get connected on Mac. (It works fine on Ubuntu)

I've checked with `nm -gU` and the signals are defined in the plugin library. Also the issue is not present if I use the same widgets in a `uic`-compiled ui file.

I'm using the connect overload that uses pointers to member functions, so the functions are there, just the Qt metaobject system seems to not be able to pick them up.